# Цикл поиска различных элементов

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, c

Подскажите цикл для поиска количества различных чисел среди элементов массива `a[10]`. Например, если я введу массив `1 2 3 1 4 8 2 3 5 3`. Получается `6` различных чисел `1 2 3 4 8 5`. Соответственно покажет `6`. Нужен только цикл сам.

Comment: Язык какой?

Comment: @Asen,
Язык си

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
...
#include<conio.h>
    using namespace std;

bool mass_find(int *mass, int col, int ch)
{
    if (col == 0)
        return false;
    bool f = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        if (mass[i] == ch) {
            f = true;
            break;
        }
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 5, 3 };
    int buffer[10];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (mass_find(buffer, counter, a[i]) == false) {
            counter++;
            buffer[counter] = a[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++)
        cout << buffer[i] << " ";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Ошибки:

1. Первый цикл у Вас 

    for(int i=1; i<=10;...) 

а надо i=0; i <10; ...

2. counter++ должен стоять после 

    buffer[counter] = a[i];

Замечания:

1. функцию можно сделать в 2 раза короче и проще. 

2. В вопросе было указано С, а не С++

Comment: Ну да)........

Answer (score 2):

Есть очень лёгкий и быстрый способ, но он требует много памяти, причём её потребление зависит от максимального числа, которое хранится в массиве:

```
unsigned int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 5, 3 };
bool table[9]={0}; //Размер этого массива равен размеру наибольшего элемента +1.
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) table[a[i]]=true; //Отмечаем, какие из этих элементов присутствуют
unsigned int b[10], n=0;
for(int i=0; i<9; i++) b[n++]=table[i];
```

В `b` содержатся уникальные элементы массива `a`, n - размер нового массива. Этот способ не полностью соответствует условию, так как выдаёт отсортированный массив. Но я не знаю, строгое это требование или нет, поэтому решил написать.

Comment: Да, но это подходит только для массива с переменными типа char или short, для int может не хватить оперативной памяти, не говоря уже про long.

Comment: Да, и отрицательными числа быть не должны.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом. Сначала сортируем массив, например, с помощью функции `qsort`. Далее в один проход анализируем массив:

```
int unique_number (const int* arr, int n, int* buff) {
    int i, res = 1;
    buff [0] = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n ; i++ ) {
        if (arr[i-1] != arr[i]) {
            buff[res++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Эта функция возвращает число значений элементов и записывает их в массив buff.

Сложность данного алгоритма составляет O(nlogn).

Comment: Можно получить объяснение от автора минуса?

Comment: Либо автор минуса не знает, что такое сортировка, либо он прочитал вопрос так:

*найти неповторяющиеся числа* 

и крайне строго подошел к buff [0] = arr[0];

Comment: Судя по примеру, ему нужен не отсортированный массив. Минусовал не я.

Comment: @mikillskegg, 

Спасиб всем кто ответил по данному вопросу,решение найдено

Comment: @mikillskegg - держите плюсег от меня =)